# Preserve the String as it

Tags: apex, json, string

This string is part of a JSON that I have. I am trying to store the JSON string that was generated using JSON.serialize method. Part of the JSONString has `"default_value": "\"   \""` as one of the JSON key value pair.

```
String bodyStr = '"default_value": "\"   \""';
System.debug(bodyStr);
```

Outputs - `"default_value": ""   ""`

How can I preserve the string as it is - `"default_value": "\"   \""` . I tried looking into String Apex class but could not find a method that supports this outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes are not special characters in Apex and don't need to be escaped. Backslashes, however, are, and do need to be escaped. If you do

```
String bodyStr = '"default_value": "\\"   \\""';
System.debug(bodyStr);
```

You will in fact get back

> 11:09:50:003 USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|"default_value": "\"   \""

Comment: I do not have control over the String. Actually that string I get using JSON.serialize method and I want to preserve it as it is.

Comment: What do you mean by preserve it? Just in a logging context or otherwise?

Comment: Meaning I would get String bodyStr = JSON.serialize(apexObj); . Then I wish to save this as a blob. I was wondering if the output of JSON.serialize(apexObj) has `"default_value": "\\"   \\""` then would it preserve it in the blob that I create?